# Connection pool manager for TcpStreams

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a client library where the base connection relies on a `std::net::TcpStream`

I am looking into the `bb8` and `r2d2` crates which implement the pooling logic for you as long as you implement the `ManageConnection` trait

I am not sure what's the best way to create a new connection:

Option 1: using `TcpStream::try_clone()` on an owned `TcpStream`

```rust
pub struct TcpStreamConnectionManager(TcpStream);

impl r2d2::ManageConnection for TcpStreamConnectionManager {
    type Connection = TcpStream;

    type Error = std::io::Error;

    fn connect(&self) -> Result<Self::Connection, Self::Error> {
        self.0.try_clone()
    }
}
```

Option 2: opening a new `TcpStream` by calling `TcpStream::connect()`

```rust
pub struct TcpStreamConnectionManager<S: ToSocketAddrs>(S);

impl<S: ToSocketAddrs + Clone + Sync + Send + 'static> r2d2::ManageConnection
    for TcpStreamConnectionManager<S>
{
    type Connection = TcpStream;

    type Error = std::io::Error;

    fn connect(&self) -> Result<Self::Connection, Self::Error> {
        TcpStream::connect(self.0.clone())
    }
}
```

Thanks

Edit:

My question is: which of these 2 options do I want ?

Comment: What's the question, exactly? `try_clone` is almost certainly not what you want, in any case, since that generates an object that operates on the same underlying TCP data stream.

Comment: that answers my question. I updated the post to make my question explicit